# Need best practices or tools for converting Microstrategy reports to SSRS platform

Tags: reporting-services, microstrategy

I need to migrate Microstrategy reports to SSRS reports.

Answer (score 0):

Visit here: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/64f2c50d-54ac-454d-b1e3-56c81d005461/need-best-practices-or-tools-for-converting-microstrategy-reports-to-ssrs-platform?forum=sqlreportingservices

As far as I am aware there aren't any converting tools for that. In the link above there are references to some useful guides to make a report in Report Builder.